# Dialogbox background not showing image in whole background in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

i've made a simple dialog program in android for login dialog for learning purpose.I have made it successfully and running it also successfully but only problem is i want an image as whole dialog background but it showing a white border default image also..i have add screen shot so that u can get idea...my code is as below:

[image]

my code is:

**dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:layout_gravity="center"   >



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:background="@drawable/dialoguebox"
            android:padding="50dp"
                   >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/usernm"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_editext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="User name" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/pwd"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_editext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chk_login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Remember me" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_small"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textColor="#f6f1eb"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**code for dialog**

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Registration.this);
            // Remove title bar

            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login_dialog);

            final EditText UserName = (EditText) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.usernm);
            final EditText Password = (EditText) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.pwd);

            Button login = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.login);
            login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // dialog.dismiss();
                    String usr = UserName.getText().toString();
                    String pwd = Password.getText().toString();
                    Intent i =new Intent(Registration.this,ProgressActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }

            });
            dialog.show();
            break;
```

Comment: try giving your image transparency with help of [this site](http://pixlr.com/) also remove padding if you dont require..

Comment: no..i dnt wnt to use any utilities...brothr...any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Custom" parent="android:Theme" >
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    </style>
```

This is the Custom Dialog that I am making

```
public class TextEditDialog extends **Dialog** implements OnClickListener {

    public TextEditDialog(Context context) {
        super(context,R.style.Theme_Custom); // ---Here I can Add this Theme
        c=context;
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
}
}
```

Comment: i have no any constructor in my dialog...where shud i put super(context,R.style.Theme_Custom);

Comment: -Bro i have put my dialog java code ..please check it...and tell me where shud i place ur "super(context,R.style.Theme_Custom);

Comment: i find the another solution thanx for help...bro..:)

Comment: so you unaccepted the answer, that's really unfair anyways all the best